# How do i connect my UITableviewcell with my PDFreader using a IBAction?

Tags: uitableview, ibaction, pdf-reader

Im working on a iPhone APP for displaying multiple PDF documents.

I have a UItableview displaying names of my pdf-files from a .plist and i have the open source VFR pdf reader (https://github.com/vfr/Reader).

i know howto connet from a UIbutton with an action to the vfr-reader:

```
- (IBAction)didClickOpenPDF1SEMCYTO {
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1SEMCYTO" ofType:@"pdf"];    

ReaderDocument *document = [ReaderDocument withDocumentFilePath:file password:nil];

if (document != nil)
{
    ReaderViewController *readerViewController = [[ReaderViewController alloc] initWithReaderDocument:document];
    readerViewController.delegate = self;

    readerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    readerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

    [self presentModalViewController:readerViewController animated:YES];
```

and

```
- (void)dismissReaderViewController:(ReaderViewController *)viewController {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];}
```

clearly i need something like it, but i cant figure out how/what, the only really similar topic was this, [Custom UITableViewCell and IBAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103643/custom-uitableviewcell-and-ibaction)
but i cant figure out if i can make use of the method in that,

any ideas please help?

Answer (score 0):

For table view, every time a row is tapped, the delegate method of table view didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called. ([More about UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate))

Make use of the indexPath parameter especially the row passed in the method below to determine which PDF you need to show in the ReaderViewController.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    ReaderViewController *readerViewController = [[ReaderViewController alloc] initWithReaderDocument:document];
    readerViewController.delegate = self;

    //determine the PDF to be shown based on indexPath.row

    readerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    readerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

    [self presentModalViewController:readerViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Remember to set your table view delegate to the view controller that implement the method above, just like how you set the delegate of your ReaderViewController.