# Object Oriented Programming hiccup in iOS view TableViewCell

Tags: ios, oop, uitableview, model-view-controller

The thing about the MVC paradigm is that your view should not know about your model. I have a custom TableCellView, which means it has no direct view controller. It belongs to a TableView. My tableView of course has a controller, MyPetTableViewController.

Anyway, my CustomTableViewCell has a number of buttons and ImageViews, everyone of them clickable. Depending on which button/imageView is clicked, I need to: go to a different tab view, or show a modal. If I were simply listening to table row, then the controller’s job would be straightforward. But how do I get the controller to listen to events within a table cell? I already thought about using `touchesEnded:withEvent` inside MyPetTableViewController but then I would not know the index in question. so really I need to know: which view inside which table row was clicked?

Comment: Add target-actions to those buttons in your cell, with the target being the cell itself. Follow a delegation pattern with your view controller as the delegate of the cell. The cell can then tell its delegate when controls are interacted with.

Comment: If you are successful, come back and post an answer here for future visitors. If not, tell us and we'd help you further.

Comment: @duci9y will do. I already wrote my method in the controller using `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndex:` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Now I am trying to learn how to add target-action from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Target-Action/Target-Action.html

Comment: @duci9y here is what I tried doing: from the storyboard I dragged and created IBOutlets for my imageViews. Then inside `awakeFromNib` I tried doing `[self.imageOne addTarget:self]` but I get the error that "No visible interface for UIImageView declares the selector addTarget:". Do you have some ideas how I might add target-actions to my images?

Comment: You can't add a target-action to an image view, it is not meant to be interacted with. Use a button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58067/discussion-between-katedral-pillon-and-duci9y).

Comment: I am still not seeing how to have the TableView's controller be the one listening to an IBAction that is implemented inside of the TableViewCell.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103643/custom-uitableviewcell-and-ibaction. It may help. I see the chat. It is not clear how that would work: that is if the IBAction is declared inside of TableViewCell. @duci9y do you mind showing an example?

Comment: You're welcome. Please post what you did as an answer and accept it, so that future visitors with the same problem can find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I finally implemented the solution

- I created IBOutlets by dragging from storyboard to the `.h` file of my CustomTableViewCell. (It's normally my practice to keep IBOutlets in the `.m` file, but since the solution to this problem needed them public, I had to put them in the `.h` file).
- In the Controller where my TableView data source and delegate methods are implemented, inside the method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I set the target of my buttons. E.g. `[cell.imageButtonOne addTarget:self action:@selector(userClicksButtonOne:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]`
- then as the final step I implemented `userClicksButtonOne` as

code:

```
- (void) userClicksButtonOne:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
     ...
    }
}
```